# Finding source of high IOWait

Tags: elasticsearch, iowait

I have a 5 node elasticsearch cluster. One host has had consistently high IOWait% (40+) for several weeks. The others seem fine (<10%).

Notable:

- Host in question is not the cluster master
- New indexes are randomly distributed among all 5 hosts
- IOTop shows that all high-wait-% processes are elasticsearch (IE no bots, viruses, etc)
- All data is stored on a SAN with a 10G bonded connection
- All hosts are configured the same

Running:

- CentOs 7.x
- 128G RAM

Suggestions on other tools to use to ferret out the problem(s)?

Comment: Can you show the output of `iotop -a -n 5` and `iostat -x -k 1 5`?

Comment: Both provide a slew of data. You want it all?

Comment: Yes, I need them to try to understand. You can use something as pastebin to show the output.